# CXF rest service - XML works fine but not JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jax-rs

I created a webapp using maven, Spring, Apache CXF.

If I set the service to produce XML, all works fine and I get result.
If I set the service to product JSON, I get no result.

this is the pom file dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

this is spring context file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.training" />

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>

<jaxrs:server id="jaxrsServer" address="/">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="libraryServices"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

this is the service

```
    @Path("/services")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface LibraryServices {

    @GET
    @Path("/book/{id}")
    public Response getBook(@PathParam("id") Integer bookId);
}
```

This is Response class (there are getters and setters)

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response {
private boolean success;

private String methodName;

private Object object;
}
```

ofcourse there is also an implementation for the service.

With XML I get good answer:

```
<response>
<methodName>getBook</methodName>
<success>false</success>
 </response>
```

With JSON I get nothing.

I think it is probably a matter of configration.

Please help me
regards, Ido

EDIT:

I found out that on a simple GET I receive 500 status. Tried to create an "out interceptor" to find out what is happening, but all seems OK. I can even see the object I wanted to return in the content of the message.

I only use a simple GET call. Than get into the server and can debug the code. 
I generate a simple collection with random fields, and then the code finishes and I get no data at all.

I generated a simple project simulating the problem but I can't load it here.

Comment: Can you show how you are sending your request? Are you are sending an `Accept` header with a MIME type of `application/json`. Are you sure no exceptions were thrown when you got the empty result?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. When you get the 500 response from the GET, is there any more info attached to the response? Also if you show us more about the request like helderdarocha suggested, that would help. And do you see any errors on the server side when this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

I needed more dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

That's all...